# Redux Share reducer between 4 state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

in my application i have duplicate reducer example :

alert.reducer.ts

```
function alertsReducer(state = initState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case '[ALERTS] GET_RESPONSE_COMPLETE':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                results: action.payload
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

user.reducer.ts

```
function usersReducer(state = initState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case '[USERS] GET_RESPONSE_COMPLETE':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                results: action.payload
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

sure in my real application have more actions that do the same thing with other context.
how i can improve for shared reducer, redux have some tools?

Comment: a reducer is not just for a single key in your state. a reducer can change all of your state, so just create a reducer that does what you wanted.

Comment: you read my question? in my application reducer do more then 1 action, but this example for repeat reducder

Comment: you understand my comment?